# Formatting and modifying panda dataframe by column

Tags: python, pandas

```
pdd = pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns =['name','rate','last','sum'])


     name            rate        last          sum
0    ACC-111         0.000110    2.658620e+05  3.096269e+04
1    ACC-222        -0.000066    6.971333e+07  1.464646e+08
2    ACC-333        -0.000085    6.054460e+02  5.270540e+02
3    ACC-444        -0.000055    1.188787e+05  6.262216e+04
4    ACC-555        -0.000064    4.670008e+05  4.194053e+05
```

I would like to multiply the rate column column by 100 and round to 4dp.
I would like to make the last and sum standard numbers instead of scientific.

How do you do these things to my panda dataframe? I can see on the panda docs like mul and round but I can't understand how to use them. thanks

Comment: Have you given a try at using them? This is quite straight forward

Comment: Look into the various methods which belong to `pd.DataFrame` and try some of them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
pdd['rate'] = pdd['rate'] * 100
pdd['rate'] = pdd['rate'].round(decimals = 4)

pdd['sum'] = pdd['sum'].apply(lambda x:'%d' %x)
pdd['last'] = pdd['last'].apply(lambda x:'%d' %x)
```